# Pattern matching email address using regular expressions

Tags: regex, email-address

Filter email address with regular expressions:  I am new to regular expressions and was hoping someone might be able to help out.

I am trying to pattern match an email address string with the following format:

FirstName.LastName@gmail.com

I want to be sure that there is a period somewhere before the '@' character and that the characters after the '@' character matches gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want some symbols before and after the dot, so I would suggest `.+\..+@gmail\.com`.

`.+` means any symbols (.) can appear 1 or more times (+)
`\.` means the dot symbol; screened with backslash to suppress the special meaning of `.`
`@gmail` and `com` should be matched exactly.

See also [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

EDIT: gmail rules for account name only allow latin letters, digits, and dots, so a better regex is
`[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com`

Comment: just to add; the `+`'s are necessary outside of your specifications @Brad in order to be a valid email (they can't start or end with a `.`) with that said though email regex get really complicated because of the specifications for valid addresses.

Comment: Thanks very much!  It works as expected and I appreciate you giving me the definitions.  I will try to figure out matching the following phone number string next.   (111) 111-1111

Comment: with such a regex, an email such as ∂øøµ$∂å¥!@gmail.com will be valid. Is there a more precise and secure regex to fix this?

Comment: @Yasky: sure; I added it to the answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 5):

check valid email

```
^(?:(?!.*?[.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9.+!%-]{1,64}|)|\"[a-zA-Z0-9.+!% -]{1,64}\")@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(.[a-z]{2,}|.[0-9]{1,})$
```

enforced rules:

- must start with alphanumeric char
- can only have alphanumeric and @._-% char
- cannot have 2 consecutives . exept for quoted string
- char before @ can only be alphanumeric and ._-%, exept for quoted string
- must have @ in the middle
- need to have at least 1 . in the domain part
- cannot have double - in the domain part
- can only have alphanumeric and .- char in the domain part
- need to finish by a valid extension of 2 or more letters
- support IP address (test@1.1.1.1)
- support for quoted user name

Comment: FYI, it yells that `test@gm.` is a valid email, which is not

Comment: fixed that and some other minor bug

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: thank you for the tips, I have made a few adjustements according to valid and invalid link listed in the wikipedia link you provide.

Comment: There is a slash missing at the domain part before the ., thus it accepts e.g. two @ or any character in the domain name. Here is a proposed fix:^(?:(?!.*?[.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9.+!%-]{1,64}|)|\"[a-zA-Z0-9.+!% -]{1,64}\")@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|[0-9]{1,})$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Unix style where `.` is any character: `.*\..*@gmail\.com`

Edit: escaped the `.` in the domain

Comment: Need to escape the . in gmail.com (e.g. gmail\.com)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need regex since your requirements are pretty specific. Not sure what language you're using, but most would support doing a split on `@` and checking for a `.`. In python:

```
name, _, domain = email.partition('@')
if '.' in name and domain == 'gmail.com':
    # valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tell us what kind of regex flavor you need however this example will fit most of them:

```
.*\..*@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I used follwing regex expression to validate the email address. Also I have added a small code snippet in C# language regarding to that.

Regex - **"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}@gmail.com$"**

Code :-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Text ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The Text that you have entered is :" + input);
            Console.ReadLine();

            string pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}@gmail.com$";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            bool results = regex.IsMatch(input);
            Console.WriteLine(results.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Emails such as **∂øøµ$∂å¥!@gmail.com** also checked and show as false here. ;-)

Comment: Seems like this won't match the period that the OP specifies. Maybe you could also clarify why it only matches between 3 and 20 characters

Comment: {3,20} means, the input text should have to have 3 to 20 number characters. Since this problem is regarding email validation, I added that as a more step of validation.

Comment: Right, but that means it will fail to match really long email addresses. It also will fail on the type of email address the OP asked about, where there's a period

Comment: 1. Fail to match really long email addresses. :- you can edit **{3,20}** as **{3,}**              2. Period :- use this regex for the entire validation **^[a-z0-9A-Z]{1,}[.][a-z0-9A-Z]{1,}@gmail.com$** And sorry for the delayed reply.